# How to get a terminal representing any character in xText

Tags: regex, eclipse, dsl, xtext, xtend

I'm using **Xtext** to develop a DSL. This DSL should accept code of any kind at a certain point. This means it should accept any character. Also, I need to record this code, without ignoring it. Does any one know a regular expression for this? I tried to use .* but it doesn't work as it expects characters that are neither digits or letters. I even tried to use "->" but it doesn't work either.

Code:

```
Param:

    'param' value=Anything;
```

...

```
Instance:

    component=[Component] name=ID 

    'call:' code=Anything;
```

What should "Antything" be?

Thanks

Comment: what stops this certain point? where does Anything stop and the next rule does begin?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich For the code I tried using " ", but after writing the first ", it expects the other ", ignoring whatever I may write in between. For the params, it's another param or the end of the configuration set, a }.

Comment: hmmm dont know if this is easily possible without switching to an external lexer and/or jflex. how do you know a configuration set ends? what is the kind of stuff that is allowed? really everything or maybe a rule like `STUFF: (ID | INT | "somekeyword" | STRING)+` helps

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Yes I believe that works. I'm only afraid I forget some character that is allowed in some language I am not yet aware of and it doesn't allow the user to write it. This is why my question is whether there is any terminal rule that accepts **any** character. The configuration is between {}, and so are the params.

Comment: the problem is: the lexer lexes the file context free => you get a stream of tokens like `ID, STRING, INT, ANY_OTHER, INT, ID, SOME_KEYWORD` independent of the place in the file

Comment: so to say ANY_OTHER might match "the rest" but not anything

Answer (score 0):

depending on what your anything is you can try something like

```
Model:
    params+=Param*;

Param:

    'param' value=Anything;

// this is a so called datatype rule
Anything :
    (ID | INT | STRING | ANY_OTHER)+
;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the `.` wildcard-operator instead of an extra parser rule? Or doesn't Xtext support that? Of course there has to be an additional lexer rule at the end of the grammar so that each input will be tokenized by the lexer...

Comment: No Lexing is not parsing

Comment: Yeah I know that... Where is the connection between your statement and mine? Afaik Xtext uses ANTLR v3 under the hood and my suggestion should work with it unless Xtext has changed something in there (or I'm missing something)

Comment: The . Operator is not for parser rules

Comment: It is... See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598461/how-to-match-any-symbol-in-antlr-parser-not-lexer ... Or was that only introduced with v4?

Comment: Xtext does not support that any token thing

Comment: Ah okay... Didn't know that. Sry